# Cannot run Nuget Package Restore from private Team City Nuget Server

Tags: teamcity, nuget

Current discussion thread: 
http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5519081#5519081

Bug Report: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-37148

**Error: Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode.**

One thing to note is that the credentials prompt is triggering on each package download instead of at the beginning.  I think this may be a bug in the way Team City is calling NuGet, but I'm not sure.

I have the "NuGet Feed Credentials" build feature configured, basic auth configured,  and I've run the feed in Firefox and got the list of packages to show up on the agent machine (with credentials required).

My build log: https://gist.github.com/tonyeung/517597ca2312dad85f62

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following is a workaround which may help you, although I was of the impression the NuGet Feed Credentials build feature was meant to fix the problem.  I was having a similar issue with the internal TeamCity NuGet feed without guest access (called *Local* in this example).

**Initial build step (command line - custom script)**

```
del /F %env.APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config
%teamcity.agent.tools.dir%\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg\tools\nuget.exe sources add -name Local -source %env.NuGetFeed%
%teamcity.agent.tools.dir%\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT.nupkg\tools\nuget.exe sources update -Name Local -User %env.BuildServiceUser% -pass %env.BuildServicePassword%
```

As I say, it's a workaround, but not too much to maintain if using templates.  Hopefully it gets you up and running.

Comment: Thanks, I actually spent about two days arriving at almost the same workaround. Instead of making a build step, I changed the agent user to a new limited user and added the sources and credentials to that user's nuget.config.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I recently came across this issue in TeamCity 9.1.7.

In my case, the issue was that I had a trailing slash on the `Server URL`, found in `Administration > Global Settings`.  Removing that slash made the authentication work correctly.

Comment: I had the same issue after migrating to TeamCity 10 from 8. In 8 it failed to build without the slash, in 10 it failed to build with it.

Answer (score 1):

For the TeamCity 8.1.2 (build 29993), I solved this issue by installing the Nuget v. 2.8.0 at the TeamCity Administration panel (I had v.2.8.2). Then I've added "Nuget Install" build step and set up the NuGet Feed Credentials build feature.
Probably, if you'll update the TeamCity it would also fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

To solve

> `http://localhost:80/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc`: The V2 feed at '`http://localhost/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc`/Packages(Id='***',Version='1.0.0')' returned an unexpected status code '401 Unauthorized'.

issue I have done:

1. create local administrator account

   ```
   net user tcbagent password123 /add
   net localgroup administrators tcbagent /add
   ```
2. attach "Logon as service" permissions (using Carbon PS helpers)

   ```
   Grant-CAPrivilege -Identity tcbagent "SeServiceLogonRight"
   ```
3. create account within TeamCity
4. run `cmd` using destination environment

   ```
   runas /user:tcbagent cmd
   ```
5. add `nuget` source with credentials

   ```
   nuget sources add -name local -source http://localhost/httpAuth/app/nuget/v1/FeedService.svc -UserName tcbagent -Password password123
   ```

   *localhost* of whatever you need

check your *teamcity-build.log* file to get something like this:

```
Starting NuGet.exe 3.5.0.1284 from C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\tools\NuGet.CommandLine.DEFAULT\tools\NuGet.exe
...
Restoring NuGet package xxxx.
...
Using credentials from config. UserName: tcbagent
```

TeamCity v9.1.7, NuGet v3.5.0-beta

I've spend 2 days to resolve it because I'm quite new with TeamCity and CI.
Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

seem like a similar issue to https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/4172.

Can you try the workaround at the bottom of the issue description?

Comment: This requires changing the nuget.config, I'm trying to get this working without that.